# Wrong query in deleting row in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, delete-row

I'm doing some delete active record but I don't know what did I do wrong.. please check my work and try to correct it.. I'm using ajax for deleting user records.. thanks

Controller:

```
//user_acc is my table name , manageuser is the view, Mod_admin is the name of my model
public function manageuser(){
    $this->load->view('template/adminhead');
    $data['user_acc'] = $this->Mod_admin->user_acc();
    $this->load->view('manageuser', $data);
}


public function delete() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->Mod_admin->deleteuser('user_acc', $id);
}
```

Model:

```
public function deleteuser($table, $id)
    {
       $this->db->delete($table,array('id'=>$id));  
    }
```

View: (manageuser.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/manageuser.css">
</head>
<title>Manage User</title>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('.id').html();


        var x =new Object();
        x = {
            'id':id,
            };

        var url ="<?php echo base_url()?>/admin/delete";
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'post',
            data:x,
            success:function(e){
                alert(e);
            }
        });

        parent.remove();
        console.log(x);
     });

});

</script>


<body>
    <div >
  <table class="table" >
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FIRST NAME</th> 
            <th>LAST NAME</th> 
            <th>USERNAME</th> 
            <th>PASSWORD</th> 
            <th>E-MAIL</th> 
            <th>CONTACT</th>
        <th colspan="2" > CONTROLS </th>
        </tr>
    <?php


                foreach($user_acc as $row){
                $id = $row->id;
                echo 

                      '<tr> 

                          <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->firstname.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->lastname.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->username.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->password.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->contact.'</td>
                          <td>'.'<a href="#" id="button" >'.'Edit</a>'.'</td>
                           <td>'.'<a href="#" id="button" class="delete" data-id="$id" >'.'Delete</a>'.'</td> 
                      </tr>';



                }
            ?>
</table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

there's no message in the alertbox once I deleted it

Comment: try firebug to trace what error its showing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no return in your ajax callback, in that *delete* function in your controller.

I would do this in your controller *delete* function:

```
public function delete() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $result = $this->Mod_admin->deleteuser('user_acc', $id);

    echo $result ? 'success' : 'failed';
}
```

and this in your model *deleteuser* function:

```
public function deleteuser($table, $id)
{
    $this->db->delete($table,array('id'=>$id));

    $result = $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ? true : false;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It says failed.. So there's something wrong in my ajax and I don't know what is it

Comment: the alert box message says "failed".. so is my query wrong or my ajax?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your ajax. I also checked your query, it doesn't seems there is anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
I always use site_url for redirections and links, and base_url when I want to load some css or js. Also add dataType: 'json'

```
**var url ="<?php echo site_url('admin/delete');  ?>";**
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'post',
            data:x,
            **dataType: 'json',**
            success:function(e){
                alert(e);
            }
        });
```

let me know

Answer (score 0):

You have made it a lot complicated please consider this

```
    <?php  foreach($user_acc as $row){  $id = $row->id; ?>


                                  <tr id="tr_<?php echo $id; ?>" >
                                  <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                                  <td><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
                                  <!-- other td's -->
                                  <td><a href="javascript:delete('<?php echo $id; ?>')">Delete</a></td> 
                                  </tr>



                       <?php } ?>
    <script>
    function delete(id){
     $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'post',
                data:{'id',id},
                success:function(e){

                  if(e=="success"){
                     $('#tr_'+id).hide();
                  }
                  else{
                     alert(e);
                  }
                }
            });

    }
    </script>
public function delete() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $result = $this->Mod_admin->deleteuser('user_acc', $id);

    echo $result ? 'success' : 'failed';
}

in model 

public function deleteuser($table, $id)
{
    $this->db->delete($table,array('id'=>$id));

    $result = $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ? true : false;

    return $result;
}
```

I have not checked your query I also recommend you to use CSRF protection